# How do you set event after a pawn takes damage?

Tags: udk, kismet

How can I set event after bot/pawn takes damage in UDK? (possibly in Kismet?)

I need to do something similar to this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjRf5lTcWLY

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [pawn events](http://wiki.beyondunreal.com/UE3%3aPawn_events_%28UDK%29), specifically the [`TakeDamage` event](http://wiki.beyondunreal.com/UE3%3aPawn_events_%28UDK%29#TakeDamage). These are very similar to the [actor events](http://wiki.beyondunreal.com/UE3%3aActor_events_%28UDK%29).

So you can extend the pawn and override `TakeDamage` to do what you want. Also, I believe you can access it [through the UI](http://cg.tutsplus.com/tutorials/udk/udk-creating-events-with-unreal-kismet/) as a pre-compiled event in Kismet.

Comment: it is not working in the UI for paws (dunno why), in UnrealScript, I don't rlly understand all of these parameters there, could you give me very simple example of TakeDamage event function in UnrealScript?

Comment: Afraid I can't write the code for you, I don't have UDK nor have I ever used UnrealScript. You'll want to look for resources for how to override UDK functions, for example [this video](http://www.3dbuzz.com/training/view/how-do-i-unreal/how-do-i/override-functions). Also, have a look at the source code for [TakeDamage](http://uncodex.com/2012-03/Source_engine/pawn.html#2481) and you'll see how the parameters are used.